# The meaning of 'the comb of the roof'

Tags: word-meaning

Is 'the comb of the roof' similar with 'the ridge of the roof'?

[image]

Here is the picture. I guess the red-checked spot is the comb of the roof. Is it right?

Comment: Probably. Can you please cite where you saw this use? Without context it is impossible to know definitively.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please upvote it. If you think it is the best answer, please select it. At the very least, leave a comment. A big problem with Stack Exchange is that there is no direct connection between the person who asks the question and the people who provide answers. In addition, of course, do not take it for granted that the same people will continue to provide answers for you without getting any direct feedback from you.

Answer (score 2):

It is a synonym for the **ridge** of a roof.

> *Ridge*
>   The line or edge formed where the two sloping sides of a roof meet at the top

(See [Oxford Dictionary online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ridge)), definition 1.1

Then the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) for "**comb**," 6e:

> The crest or ridge of a roof. *dialect*

Here are two of the four examples from the OED

> 1869   ‘M. Twain’ Innocents Abroad xviii. 174   From the eaves to the comb of the roof.
>   1888   F. T. Elworthy W. Somerset Word-bk.   Comb,..2. The ridge of a roof.

See also:
*[Shelters, Shacks and Shanties](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/28255/28255-h/28255-h.htm)*  (page 14):

> Continue thus to the comb of the roof, then over the part where the bark of the sides meets on the top lay another layer of bark covering **the crown, ridge, comb, or apex** and protecting it from the rain.